# calculate elapsed time(second time mark - first time mark)

Tags: android

I have service(Service has a Broadcast receiver, that listens for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`), that I want to calculate time passed between two time marks, this what I have:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                long time;
                long startTime=0;

                    if(OldLevel==0){
                    OldLevel=level;
                    startTime = System.nanoTime();

                    }
                    else{

                        time=System.nanoTime()-startTime;
                        startTime=System.nanoTime();  //edited


                    Log.e("inFFFF","FFFF "+time);// I somehow here get 16243428223995 nanoseconds which are too large because in reality it just take 1-2min.
                    }

                }
```

If you are able please: 1. Tell me why time is larger than expected 2. Or suggest better way to calculate time that is being elapsed.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use `System.currentMillis()`? Of course, that is less precise, but may be this alternative is good enough, isn't it?

Comment: I used millis before, inaccurate result as well :/

Comment: @whiteLT if the first condition is true than it will never go to the else, so at a time one condition will satisfy so you'll get the actual time but not the elapsed time

Comment: I guess that `startTime` has not been initialized as expected when running the line `time=System.nanoTime()-startTime;`. Have you checked the values in the debugger?

Comment: @Pragnani if the firs condition is true, I only want to mark time and that all. So when condition two is active I could calculate, how much time it took

Comment: @André I will check and write ASAP

Comment: Ok, reading through this I think with *"between two time marks"* you mean between two `onReceive()` calls, right? If so you might need to decare `startTime` as a `static` `volatile` member of your receiver class. The receiver object lives only for a short time; check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle too

Comment: Thank you all for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code example you assign startTime with a value, only if condition 1 is met.
(else you calculate `System.nanoTime()-startTime` where startTime is 0)

So in fact you are comparing now time to 0 which is the initial value of start time.
this is wrong. nano time is used to measure elapsed time.
you should always compare  System.nanoTime() to other calls of System.nanoTime().
see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()

maybe try something like this :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

                long time;
                long startTime= System.nanoTime();

                    if(....){

                    startTime = System.nanoTime();

                    }
                    else{

                        time=System.nanoTime()-startTime;



                    Log.e("inFFFF","FFFF "+time);// I somehow here get 16243428223995 nanoseconds which are too large because in reality it just take 1-2min.
                    }

                }
```

Comment: I edited my example, to show that I already took safe precautions for this.

Comment: first time this service is launched it's only making a time stamp. I edited one more time for you better understanding what I want to do

Comment: @whiteLT, maybe you want startTime to be a member of your class? as it stands it is a local variable so it is always 0 in your else {} section.

Comment: You probably right, I will now check. So all this time I was wrong? I thought that if variable is outside if and else, then it is same for both?

Comment: It is the same for both. However, you want it to "remember" the value once you leave the context of the method for the next time it is called. therfor you need a class member , not a local variable.

Comment: You are right, but that other person is right too, whose answer I should accept?

Comment: whose answer to accept is for you to decide.glad to have helped- good luck

Answer (score 1):

At the time of `else` start time is always zero. so you need to capture the start time in the beginning it self.

i.e

```
long startTime=System.nanoTime();
```

otherwise keep the remaining code as it is

Comment: How can start time be always zero if I declare it and even take precaution if firs condition is not met?

Comment: Because of this      long startTime=0;

Comment: If it goes to the else condition what is the value of start time, it is not updated.

Comment: I have understand your problem based on the comments in @omer answer, you need to declare it as a field and initialize it with zero. remove start time=0 in your onReceive

Comment: You are right, but that other person is right too, whose answer I should accept?